# How to properly convert a Vue application to Ionic 4 Vue?

Tags: ionic-framework, vue.js, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm trying to convert an existing *VueJS* project to use *Ionic 4* and *Ionic Native* plugins. It's my first time using *Ionic 4* and it looks like the *Ionic CLI* only allows you to build *Angular* based apps so far. The *Vue* integration needs to be done manually.

The [documentation](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/vue) I've found so far allows me to consume *Ionic* components but does not seem to be enough to properly setup *Ionic* in my project.

After going through the steps and finally adding `Vue.use(Ionic)` to my main entry point, running `ionic --help` still tells me that my *project is not an Ionic project*, probably because I do not have a `ionic.config.json` available at root level. I then run `ionic init`, this config file gets generated, but it is now telling me to *`provide the ionic:serve npm script`* so that it can serve my project (`"type": "custom"`). How can I setup all the required scripts that *Ionic* needs ?

I will need to have this setup to be able to add *Ionic Native plugins*, build my app on different platforms, etc.

I could not find any information so far neither in the docs, nor in here.

Does anyone have further information about this ?

Comment: I dont think you can convert vue project into ionic like this. Ionic has complete different architecture. If you want to use plugins, see how to use cordova with vue. https://itnext.io/make-hybrid-platform-cordova-vue-webpack-2fb7031c4f9b

Comment: Also the documentation you are referring to says that its  an alpha release of @ionic/vue so there are some missing pieces. Its not a good idea to convert vue into ionic.

Comment: As of yet the is no direct way of converting but most of your vue code should still work after you update the project structure. In this article https://medium.com/@dlodeprojuicer/using-cordova-in-an-ionic-vue-app-the-almost-complete-guide-d6423c248257 you might give you some insight, though it is not exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit late but it can be helpful for someone else. I'm in the same situation, and yes, now it's possible. From ionic docs:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cdn#ionic-vue

Comment: Nice! Thank you

Comment: Quick tip: the documentation doesn't say, but we need to use: `ionic init` after